# Is Augur use on topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

https://augur.net/ is a trading and betting platform used to predict real-world events using Ethereum. But is the use of Ethereum merely *coincidental* to this as a stand-alone subject for a *new* site?

[**Have a look at this proposal — Augur**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106367?phase=definition). Would the subjects covered by this proposal be welcomed and on topic for *this* site? Or does it belong somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

Prediction markets if successful may ultimately have millions of worldwide with a wide variety of backgrounds. I agree with 5chdn about the "why" component of the LMSR question being likely to start opinionated discussion. However, I  believe that economics, game theory, psychology, statistics and finance (in addition to blockchain technology and Ethereum related questions) are integral components of predictions markets and should be topic in an Augur Stack Exchange site.

The point 5chdn makes about Airbitz Edge Security being more closely connected to Bitcoin than Ethereum is also a valid point. Prediction markets such as [Hivemind](http://bitcoinhivemind.com/) are already planned for Bitcoin and more will eventually be built on other blockchains (including privacy centric blockchains like Monero) in the future. Augur will overlap with many subject areas not related to Ethereum. It has more in common with Hivemind (in terms of likely Stack Exchange questions) than it does with Ethereum. In fact the very concept of Augur was derived from the [Truthcoin whitepaper](http://www.truthcoin.info/papers/truthcoin-whitepaper.pdf) which Paul Sztorc originally designed for Bitcoin.

Therefore I suggest that Augur be allowed to launch its own site so that its scope is not limited to include only Ethereum related questions. However the new Augur site might consider allowing questions about [Gnosis](https://gnosis.pm/), [Hivemind](http://bitcoinhivemind.com/) and other prediction markets that will launch in the next few years

Comment: While some Augur questions will directly be related to Ethereum, many will not. Augur (with or without the inclusion of other prediction markets) is important and broad enough to merit its own Stack Exchange site

Answer (score 3):

General personal feeling: **Yes**, because it is fully operating on top of the Ethereum stack. Here is the related tag: [augur](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augur), 7 questions asked this quarter.

---

Going through the example questions with highest score:

> 1. Are there any hardware wallets capable of storing REP? [14]

**Yes**, REP is a token on the Ethereum platform, valid question and well on-topic.

> 2. What is the difference between LMSR and Liquidity-Sensitive LMSR (LS-LMSR) and why has Augur decided to focus on the later? [14]

**No**, while I think everything Augur-related is on-topic, this question is simply not really related with Augur. The *why* part actually tends to start an opinionated discussion. Economics has this question: [Difference between LMSR and Liquidity-Sensitive LMSR](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15239)

> 3. What is Airbitz Edge Security and what features does it bring to the Augur account creation process? [13]

**Maybe**, Airbitz Edge Security is an interesting authentication management system, however, as far as I know it's based on the Bitcoin platform. This question might also work out on Bitcoin Stack Exchange: [questions tagged with [airbitz]](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbitz).

> 4. Can I use Augur without owning REP? [13]

**Yes**, on-topic just like the first question.

> 5. What is a Schelling Point and how is it relevant to Augur? [13]

**Maybe**, I'm no friend of *what is* questions, but at some point they are valid. '*What is a Schelling Point?*' would be off-topic. However, '*How many transactions are needed to establish a Schelling focal point on the Augur platform?*' would be on-topic.

> 6. What is a stablecoin and why would it be of importance to Augur? [12]

**Yes**, A valid canonical question which is put in context of Augur. Here is the Ethereum version: [How would stablecoins work on Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2739/87)

> 7. What advantages does the Serpent programming language offer Augur developers compared to Solidity? [10]

**Yes**, both [serpent](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpent) and [solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity) are native Ethereum programming languages.

> 8. How many REP tokens exist and will the supply ever change? [10]

**Yes**, on-topic just like the first question.

> 9. Is there a procedure for challenging the decision of reporters? [10]

**Maybe**, this is a very specific question which would be on topic for Ethereum Stack Exchange, but (if existing) better suited for an Augur-specific site.

> 10. What is the origination and meaning of the name Augur? [10]

**Yes**, as Augur is on topic.

---

Going through the questions confirms my personal feeling, however, this does not imply that I think there should be no separate Stack Exchange site for Augur. That's up to the community.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I would note (only for the big picture) that it took 12 months and more than 4,500 questions to attract 8 questions total in this subject space. This proposal **raced through to Commitment in 16 days.** It's just another consideration.

Comment: I just found this very related discussion, which exclusively features augur as on-topic example: [Are questions on specific DAPPs on or off topic?](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/36)

Comment: Excellent, thanks.